# "Custom Map Field" features

Tags: blackberry, gps

There does not seem to be a lot of information on the "Custom Map Field" features. I am adding Images to my custom MapField and would like to make those images clickable. If anyone is familiar with this please let me know and ill post my Code snippet , etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two MapField classes in the API: the old [`net.rim.device.api.lbs.MapField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/), available since OS 4.5, and the newer [`net.rim.device.api.lbs.maps.ui.MapField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/), available from OS 6.0 onwards. For the newest one, the default action when an item is clicked is to show a dialog with info, but I think you could listen for clicks by setting a custom [`MapAction`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/maps/ui/MapAction.html) instance in the MapField. If not possible, then for both old and new mapfields you can override `navigationClick` and look for the nearest clickable item to the map center. This nearest neighbour lookup should be optimized in case you have a large number of clickable items (for instance, skipping all non visible elements). For touchscreen enabled devices, you can override `touchEvent`, retrieve the clicked position and do the same.

Actually both approaches are compatible.